# uiscrollview change image in imageview

Tags: ios, image, sdk, uiscrollview, uiimageview

i have a scroll view with 10 pages and un the last 6 I have an ImageView.

When I Tap on a Button my screen jumps to the right ImageView. But how can I change the Image on this ImageView on the Button click event?

Any Ideas?

`ImageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mhb2-1.jgp" ];`

doesn't do anything

I create the ImageView in the ViewController.h

and in the "view did load":

```
if (pageNumber == 6) {
        ImageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 10.0, 50.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
        [ImageView1 setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
        [self.view addSubview:ImageView1];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

give tags to your buttons,
int selectedButtonTag;
when button gets tapped
use selectedButtonTag=button.Tag;

```
if(selectedButtonTag==2){
        [ImageView1 setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
}
if(selectedButtonTag==3){
        [ImageView1 setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"]];
}
```

Comment: don't understand what you mean.  but you need == in your if statement and not =

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing : `[scrollView addSubView:ImageView1];` ??

Comment: Okay, then to differentiate the image on buttons click, take a look at bhuXan's answer.